# 2000m spots in Guns of Icarus?

Tags: guns-of-icarus, guns-of-icarus-online

How the hell do you get these? I've been on pretty big maps like Dunes, zoomed in all the way with my Spyglass, and the enemies I see are either too far away to spot, or when I do spot them, they are too close to count for 2000m. Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this and is still wondering what the best map is, I got a response from the Devs on Twitter with their suggestions:

[image]